# Only create Perl hash key/value pair if value is defined

Tags: perl

I wish to create a key/value pair in a hash only if I have a defined value to assign.

I am currently doing this:

```
$hash{key1} = $val1 if defined $val1;
```

which is OK - but can become annoying when `$val1` is complicated.   Is there a way that I can neatly get the same outcome without having to say `$val1` twice?  The test script below might help clarify what I am trying to achieve.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More tests => 1;

my %hash;
my $val1 = undef;    # Explicitly undef
my $val2 = 10;
$hash{key1} = $val1 if defined $val1;
$hash{key2} = $val2 if defined $val2;
my %expected = ('key2', 10);
is_deeply(\%hash, \%expected, 'Hashes compare');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a subroutine.

```
set( \%hash, $key1, $val1 );
set( \&hash, $key2, $val2 );

sub set {
    my $hash = shift;
    my $key  = shift;
    my $val  = shift;

    $hash->{$key} = $val if defined $val;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andy - I moved the answered question to this one as it is not just functionally equivalent - it is neat and clear - which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you have many such values to check you can use grep/list:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my %hash;
my $val1 = undef;    
my $val2 = 10; 
$hash{$_->[0]} = $_->[1] for grep { defined $_->[1] } 
    ['key1', $val1], ['key2', $val2];
```

Or you can filter the hash after populating it blindly:

```
$hash{key1} = $val1;
$hash{key2} = $val2;
%hash = map { $_, $hash{$_} } grep { defined $hash{$_} } keys %hash;
```

Comment: Thank you @perreal - much appreciated.  That is certainly functionally equivalent and meets the requirement that the value is only stated once.  I probably wouldn't use in my context because what I am gaining in reducing repetition I lose in readability.

Comment: I've edited your code to grep for `{ defined $_->[1] }` instead of just `{ $_->[1]`. As written, it would have excluded keys with a value of 0, an empty string, or the string "0", as those values are considered to be "false".

Comment: Ideally I was hoping there was something along the lines of `$hash{key} = if defined $val;` - that is some flow control statement like trailing if that can also work as an RValue.   But as it doesn't look like there is any neater way I have marked this response as the answer.   Thank you Dave and perreal.

Comment: @RossAttrill, I added another way I thought of, but yes there seems to be no way of doing this using a modifier.

Comment: Thank you perreal - I think cleaning up afterwards as per your second approach is neat and clear.